# JavaScript counter - immediately implement comma on page load

Tags: javascript, counter

I have a JavaScript counter (that works beautifully) and have now added commas, which works too.  The commas show up, BUT it only shows when the counter increments.  It's actually 4 counters and a total counter. 3 of the counters increment so often that it's not a problem, but I need the commas to show up on page load as there is a background and not just when the counter increments.  I think it has to do with where I call the addCommas(), but can't get it working when I call it differently.  I'll throw in some of the code:

```
var crate_msInterval = crate_interval * 1000;

crate_count = parseInt((now - start_date)/crate_msInterval) * increment + start_value;

document.getElementById('crate_counter').innerHTML = crate_count;
setInterval("crate_count += increment; document.getElementById('crate_counter').innerHTML = addCommas(crate_count);", crate_msInterval);
```

And then the commas function I'm using:

```
function addCommas(str){
   var arr,int,dec;
   str += '';

   arr = str.split('.');
   int = arr[0] + '';
   dec = arr.length>1?'.'+arr[1]:'';

   return int.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g,"$1,") + dec;
}
```

I hope I'm being clear enough. Any suggestions?

Comment: Run `addCommas(crate_count);` in the same code. Also, use `setTimeout(function(){ .... }, crate_msInterval);` instead of `setTimeout(" ... ", crate_msInterval);` ...

Comment: Thx for the super fast response everyone, I just ended up calling addCommas(twice) - like this:

    var crate_msInterval = crate_interval * 1000;

 crate_count = parseInt((now - start_date)/crate_msInterval) * increment + start_value;

 document.getElementById('crate_counter').innerHTML = addCommas(crate_count);
 setInterval("crate_count += increment; document.getElementById('crate_counter').innerHTML = addCommas(crate_count);", crate_msInterval);

it works fine.  Not sure how ethical this is, but it works:)

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function `addCommas` on page load and set the element innerHTML. Also you can pass an anonymous function to setInterval method instead of specifying the code as a string.

```
var crate_msInterval = crate_interval * 1000;

var crate_count = parseInt((now - start_date)/crate_msInterval) * increment + start_value;

document.getElementById('crate_counter').innerHTML = crate_count;
setInterval(function(){
     crate_count += increment; 
     document.getElementById('crate_counter').innerHTML = addCommas(crate_count);
}, crate_msInterval);

//This will set the initial value formatted with comma's
document.getElementById('crate_counter').innerHTML = addCommas(crate_count);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your  tag, you can have an onload parameter which invokes the javascript passed to it after the page has loaded.